# Mysql if statement to determine table

Tags: mysql

I'm wondering if I can use MySQL IF to select the table to update. I'm trying something like this:

```
UPDATE IF(:listId = 'global', `profanity`,`accountProfanity`) SET `active` = IF(`active` = 1,0,1) WHERE `id` = 1
```

`:listId` can ben a string `global` or numeric.
When :listId is numeric, I want to update table `profanity`, else, I want to update `accountProfanity`.
When I run this query I get this as a result:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF('global' = 'global', `profanity`,`accountProfanity`) SET `active` = IF(`activ' at line 1
```

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Where are you getting the value of listId from ?

Comment: Calling a function. But that is not really relevant I think. The parameters are added correctly by PDO SQL. MySQL fails to execute my IF statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use prepared statement for this:

```
SET @id = 1;    
SET @table_name = IF(:listId = 'global', `profanity`,`accountProfanity`);
SET @update_query = CONCAT('UPDATE ', @table_name, '
                              SET active = IF(active = 1,0,1) 
                                WHERE id = ', @id);
PREPARE stmt FROM @update_query;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```